# Is it possible to make a function self aware without external input

Tags: javascript, function

**Background**

I want a function keeping track of its own state:

```
var myObject = {

    myFunction: function () {

        var myself = this.myFunction;
        var firstTime = Boolean(!myself.lastRetry);

        if (firstTime) {

            myself.lastRetry = Date.now();
            return true;
        }

        // some more code

    }
}
```

The problem with the above code is that the value of `this` will depend on the site of the function call. I want the function to be able to refer to itself without using:

- `myObject.myFunction`
- `.bind()`
- `.apply()`
- `.call()`

**Question**

Is it possible to give a function this kind of self awareness independent of its call site and without any help from external references to it?

Comment: You mean like...SkyNet?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Do you just want the one instance? (As an aside, you don't need the `Boolean()` wrapper in the above code.)

Comment: Voting to close on account of this is how the world ends.

Comment: Thats a good one @T.J. Crowder. Actually that kind of awareness could probably save me many hours of work ;)

Comment: @rabbitco: Yeah, being blown away in a nuclear apocalypse does tend to lighten one's workload. :-)

Comment: You mean I cannot rely on "containing" it in my Javascript object .... ?

Comment: What's wrong with `bind`? That's the standard way of making sure your `this` is what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to store that state on the function instance, give the function a name, and use that name within it:

```
var myObject = {

    myFunction: function theFunctionName() {
    //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------------------- name
        var firstTime = Boolean(!theFunctionName.lastRetry);
    //                           ^--------------------------- using it
        if (firstTime) {

            theFunctionName.lastRetry = Date.now();
    //      ^------------------------------------------------ using it
            return true;
        }

        // some more code

    }
};
```

You'd do that whenever you want to use a function recursively as well. When you give a name to a function that way (putting the name after `function` and before `(`), that name is in-scope within the function's own code. (It's not in-scope for the code containing the function if it's a function expression, but it is if it's a function declaration. Yours is an expression.)

That's a *named function expression* (where previously you had an *anonymous function expression*). You may hear warnings about NFEs, but the issues various JavaScript implementations had with them are essentially in the past. (IE8 still handles them incorrectly, though: More in [this post on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html).)

You might consider keeping that state somewhere private, though, via an IIFE:

```
var myObject = (function(){
    var lastRetry = null;
    return {
        myFunction: function() {
            var firstTime = Boolean(!lastRetry);
            if (firstTime) {

                lastRetry = Date.now();
                return true;
            }

            // some more code

        }
    };
})();
```

Now, nothing outside that outer anonymous function can see `lastRetry` at all. (And you don't have to worry about IE8, if you're supporting stubborn XP users. :-) )

---

Side note: The unary `!` operator **always** returns a boolean, so your

```
var firstTime = Boolean(!theFunctionName.lastRetry);
```

...is exactly equivalent to:

```
var firstTime = !theFunctionName.lastRetry;
```

...but with an extra unnecessary function call. (Not that it hurts anything.)

Comment: Note that both methods work without needing to have the function as an object method.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, simply give your function an internal named representation and it can refer to itself from there. For example...

```
var obj = {
    doThings:function doThingsInternal(arg1, arg2) {
        console.log(arg1, arg2);
        for (var arg in doThingsInternal.arguments) {
            console.log(arg);
        }
    }
};

obj.doThings('John', 'Doe');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple Closure, if you are not too bent on keeping state existence knowledge within the function. But I guess you don't want that. Another way to do this could be changing the function itself on the first call. Benefits, no/less state variables needed and no costly checks on subsequent calls! -

```
    var myObject = {

    myFunction: function () {
       // Whatever you wanna do on the first call...
       // ...
       // And then...
       this.myFunction = function(){
         // Change the definition to whatever it should do
         // in the subsequent calls.
       }
       // return the first call value.
    }
};
```

You can extend this model to any states by changing the function definition per your state.